# Make all html tags alt values inside selenium Webelement into one string

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

Is there a robust method for casting all alt values inside the img tags into strings to formulate a sentence, without losing the position of both texts:
(Note: the amount of img tags between the two texts can vary)

```
<img alt="one">
Bobby gave: 
<img alt="two">
<img alt="two">
<img alt="two">
 and took 
<img alt="three">
<img alt="four">
```

desired output:

```
sentence = "one Bobby gave: two two two and took three four"
```

I tried:

```
images = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "img")
sentence = [img.get_attribute("alt") for img in images]
```

But now i dont get the two texts "Bobby gave" and "and took" between the right tags

Comment: Would it be possilble to just get the alts attribute between the first and second text in one list and the alts after the second text in the another?

Comment: I see that you haven't responded to my answer. Is there something that I can fix?

Answer (score 2):

I'm no master of `Selenium`, so here's an alternative using [`BeautifulSoup`](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) which is a tool that goes hand in hand with `Selenium`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<img alt="one">
Bobby gave: 
<img alt="two">
<img alt="two">
<img alt="two">
 and took 
<img alt="three">
<img alt="four">
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
images = soup.find_all("img")

print(
    " ".join(
        str(img["alt"])
        + " "
        + img.find_next(text=True).get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
        for img in images
    )
)
```

Output:

```
one Bobby gave: two  two  two and took three  four
```

Answer (score -1):

Let say HTML looks like (add a parent node to your sample)

```
<div>
  <img alt="one">
  Bobby gave: 
  <img alt="two">
  <img alt="two">
  <img alt="two">
   and took 
  <img alt="three">
  <img alt="four">
</div>
```

We can get all parents' node children (images and text nodes)

```
child_nodes = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('div').childNodes;")
```

And then extract required values

```
nodes = []
for child in child_nodes:
    try:
        if child['textContent'].strip():
            nodes.append(child['textContent'].strip())
    except:
        nodes.append(child.get_attribute('alt'))
sentence = ' '.join(nodes)
```

Output:

```
'one Bobby gave: two two two and took three four'
```